# How To Get Rid Of Giant Gap On Bootstrap Mobile Site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on converting my site to a mobile version. All of the content lies withing bootstrap columns.

It looks decent on mobile, except the fact that there's a ~1000px blank gap on the right side of the page. The body has a width of 370px, and I put a red border on everything; absolutely nothing is leaking into the blank space.

How can I get rid of the giant blank area? Again, the body has a width of 370px and nothing is leaking into the area. Overflow: hidden also doesn't work.

Please look at a demo here: http://gyazo.com/b8b18748aba8270b79f8405999ace254

Comment: Post the HTML that you're using!

Answer (score 0):

have you got this meta tag in the head?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

Its hard to know for sure that the issue is though without any code supplied

Comment: Agree with this, except the `maximum-scale=1.0` at the end, which isn't user-friendly, so is best left out in most cases.

Comment: depends if you want the user to be able to zoom in or not, depends on your requirements

Comment: Indeed, but except in rare circumstances, making this decision on behalf of your visitors is not good. It drives me nuts when I try to zoom in on something and the developer has needlessly decided I'm not allowed to.

Comment: fair enough, but this is unrelated to the question asked